# How are variables assigned in PHP classes?

Tags: php

I did an exercise in [codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com) related to objects in PHP. It asked me to define a public variable `$name` in class `Cat`:

```
    <?php
        class Cat {

            public $isAlive = true;
            public $numLegs = 4;
            public $name;

            public function __construct( $name ) { 
                $this->name = $name;
            }

            public function meow() {
                return "Meow meow. " . $this->name . "<br>";
            }
        }

        $cat1 = new Cat( "CodeCat" );
        echo $cat1->meow();

    ?>
```

Is this `public $name;` line actually needed? As I understand this, I call special function `__construct` with an argument value `CodeCat`. Then this `CodeCat` is assigned to variable `$this->name` and that's what I use later in function `meow`. If I comment out the `public $name;` line, then this does not affect the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this *public $name;* line actually needed? ... If I comment out the
>   *public $name;* line, then this does not affect the result.

PHP will create properties on your objects on request, even if you never formally declared them.

```
Class Thing{}
$a = new Thing();
$a->name = 'John';
echo $a->name; // John
echo $a->age; // doesn't break script but PHP gives 'Notice: undefined property'
```

[**Run it here**](https://3v4l.org/Z9tlm)

So your code runs either way because PHP adds the `name` property when you set it to something inside `__construct()`.  Since properties are public by default, you get the same result.

This code design (using properties without declaring them) is a poor habit for several reasons including:

- It's a nightmare for others who want to use or interact with your code
- It's a nightmare for you if you're dealing with anything more than a very simple script. In a large application it will be impossible to know *does this instance of `Cat` have a name?*, *what about this instance?*, *what other properties does it have anyway?* None of these will be easy to answer if you add properties dynamically across different functions, or worse, different files.
- Calling code has no guarantee that a property exists, so your program will likely have many more bugs
- IDEs and code editors have no way to know the shape of your objects, so you're deprived of powerful tooling. Your scripts will take longer to write

Answer (score 0):

Public variables allow you to modify them directly as fields as instead of going through public methods. Add the following lines:

```
    $cat1 = new Cat( "CodeCat" );
    echo $cat1->meow();

    $cat1->name = "Another Cat";
    echo $cat1->meow();
```

You will see:

```
Meow meow. CodeCat<br>
Meow meow. Another Cat<br>
```

You are able to change the value of $name even after construction.

### With a private property:

Change the accessor of $name to private from public, you will get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot access private property Cat::$name
```

when trying to assign it a value from the $cat1 object.